# Convert an OVF file for use in VMWare Server

Tags: vmware-server

I have a virtual appliance OVF File and I am trying to figure out how to use it in VMWare Server. I saw [this](http://www.webs05.com/2009/03/02/converting-ova-files-for-use-in-vmware-server.html) article that describes using the VMWare Converter tool but when I try to select my OVA file as a source, I get an error that says "The file you selected is not a valid source." Is it possible to use an OVA file directly in VMWare Server? If not, is it possible to convert it into something that is usable in VMWare Server?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ovftool - http://www.vmware.com/resources/techresources/1013